# How to reset the values of a cloned object using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find and clone an element inside my DOM. Once cloned, I want to clear out the element values then append them at the bottom of a container.

For some reason I can't seems to clear out the value. Currently the row gets appended but with the same values as the first row. I want to clone the object and leave out the values.

How can I fix the below code to clone everything but the values?

```
// replaces the index of each element to the giving index. so Title[0][name] will become Title[index][name]...
window.getContent = function (html, index) {
    return html.replace(/_\d+__/g, '_' + index + '__')
        .replace(/\[\d+\]/g, '[' + index + ']');
}

$(function(){

    $('#addRow').click(function(){

        // find the first row inside #container
        // clone it, find any input inside of it and set its value to empty string
        var template = $('#container .row').first().clone().find(':input').val('').end();

        // find the current count of the rows inside the container
        var index = $('#container .row').length;

        // replace the index inside the element name to the correct index
        var content = getContent(template.prop('outerHTML'), index);

        // append the new element on to the container
        $('#container').append(content);
    });
});
```

Here is a [JS Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/94073/) with the above code in action

Comment: Did you mean to initialize the inputs with `value=123` etc?

Comment: @Akrion yes, on an edit screen the values are preset. and the user has the option to change the value or create new row

Comment: Ok then my answer should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
var template = $('#container .row').first().clone().find(':input').attr('value','').end();
```

Should do it for you.

The problem is that `val` would not take care of the `default value` attribute which is why `attr` is needed.

See it [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/akrion/DTcHh/94087/)

Comment: #%#&! Something so silly wasted lots of my time. +1 for teaching me something new today

Answer (score 2):

`val()` sets the element's `value` property on the object. It does not change the `value` html attribute. Due to this when you get the outerHTML and change the html text you haven't saved the value changes, so the value html attributes are going to be used when you append that html text.

Instead just modify the name properties on the elements themselves instead of modifying the html text. And finally append the cloned element instead of the html text:

```
var template = $('#container .row').first().clone();
var index = $('#container .row').length;

template.find(":input").val('').each(function(){
  //modify the element's name property
  this.id = this.id.replace(/_\d+__/g, '_' + index + '__');
  this.name = this.name.replace(/\[\d+\]/g, '[' + index + ']');
});
$('#container').append(template);
```

---

Demo

```js
window.getContent = function(html, index) {
  return html.replace(/_\d+__/g, '_' + index + '__')
    .replace(/\[\d+\]/g, '[' + index + ']');
}

$(function() {

  $('#addRow').click(function() {
    var template = $('#container .row').first().clone();
    var index = $('#container .row').length;

    template.find(":input").each(function(){
      //might as well set value here since
      //we are looping anyway
      this.value = "";
      //modify the element's id property
      this.id = this.id.replace(/_\d+__/g, '_' + index + '__');

     //modify the element's name property
      this.name = this.name.replace(/\[\d+\]/g, '[' + index + ']');
    });
    $('#container').append(template);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <input id="test_0__name" name="test[0][name]" value="test">
    <input id="test_0__game" name="test[0][game]" value="test 1">
    <input id="test_0__lame" name="test[0][lame]">
    <input id="test_0__fame" name="test[0][fame]" value="test 3">
    <input id="test_0__dame" name="test[0][dame]" value="test 4">
  </div>
</div>
<button id="addRow">Add</button>
```